# QT debug OK, with release no signals

Tags: c++, qt, signals, release, qftp

at the beginning sry for my english :-D

I have QT 5.6 and the QT Creator IDE.

If i compile my programm in debug mode, no problem.

If i compile in release mode i dont get any signal from QFTP

```
    FTPManager::FTPManager(QObject *parent)
    {

       m_pFTP = new QFtp(parent->parent());

       connect(m_pFTP, SIGNAL(commandFinished(int,bool)),this, SLOT(ftpCommandFinished(int,bool)));
       connect(m_pFTP, SIGNAL(stateChanged(int)),this, SLOT(ftpStateChanged(int)));
       connect(m_pFTP, SIGNAL(dataTransferProgress(qint64,qint64)),this, SLOT(updateDataTransferProgress(qint64,qint64)));
       connect(m_pFTP, SIGNAL(readyRead()),this,SLOT(readData()));
       connect(m_pFTP, SIGNAL(listInfo(QUrlInfo)), this, SLOT(GetList(QUrlInfo)));
       connect(m_pFTP, SIGNAL(commandStarted(int)),this,SLOT(ftpCommandStarted(int)));
    }



    MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
    {
        ui->setupUi(this);

        m_pRezepturVerwaltung = new RezepturVerwaltung(ui);
        m_pFTPManager = new FTPManager(this);

        connect(m_pFTPManager, SIGNAL(DownloadFinish()), m_pRezepturVerwaltung, SLOT(AktualisiereShowProgparOrdnerstruktur()));
        connect(m_pFTPManager, SIGNAL(OwndataTransferProgress(qint64,qint64)),m_pRezepturVerwaltung, SLOT(updateDataTransferProgress(qint64,qint64)));
        connect(m_pRezepturVerwaltung, SIGNAL(SignalUpload(QString, QString, QString, QString)),
        m_pFTPManager, SLOT(Upload(QString, QString, QString, QString)));
        connect(m_pRezepturVerwaltung, SIGNAL(SignalDownload(QString, QString, QString, QString)),
        m_pFTPManager, SLOT(Download(QString, QString, QString, QString)));
    }
```

I have the Q_Object in the class:

```
    class FTPManager : public QObject
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
       explicit FTPManager(QObject *parent = 0);
       ~FTPManager();
       QFtp * m_pFTP;
    };
```

I tried to clean and then qmake.

I delete the hole compling dir.

EDIT:

i call void FTPManager::downloadMehrereDateien() if i want download any file.

```
    void FTPManager::downloadMehrereDateien()
    {
        //Überprüfen ob es noch Dateien zu abbarbeiten gibt
        if (!m_strukDownloadFile.xAktive)
        {
            if(m_lDownloadqueue.count() > 0)
            {
                m_strukDownloadFile = m_lDownloadqueue.takeAt(0);
                m_strukDownloadFile.xAktive = true;
            }else
            {
                m_pFTP->close();
                return;
            }
        }

        if(!m_struktStatus.Connected)
        {
            connectToFtp(m_strukDownloadFile.sIP);
            m_pFTP->error();
        }else
        {
            if(!m_struktStatus.LoggedIn)
            {
                LoginToFtp();
            }else
            {
                m_pFTP->cd("StorageCard");

                m_pFTP->cd("DATA");

                int fileErweiterung = 1;
                QString sDateiUndSpeicherpfad = "", sDownlodFileName = "";


                sDateiUndSpeicherpfad = m_strukDownloadFile.sSpeicherPfad + m_strukDownloadFile.sFileName + m_strukDownloadFile.sDateiendung;
                sDownlodFileName = m_strukDownloadFile.sFileName + m_strukDownloadFile.sDateiendung;

                actionFile = new QFile(sDateiUndSpeicherpfad);
                while( actionFile->exists() )
                {
                    sDateiUndSpeicherpfad =m_strukDownloadFile.sSpeicherPfad + m_strukDownloadFile.sFileName + QString::number(fileErweiterung) + ".TAB";
                    actionFile->setFileName(sDateiUndSpeicherpfad);
                    fileErweiterung++;
                };


                if (!actionFile->open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
                {
                    qDebug() << "Datei kann nicht geöffnet werden";
                    delete actionFile;
                    m_strukDownloadFile.xAktive = false; //ToDo: Später mehrere versuche dann erst false
                    downloadMehrereDateien();
                }else
                {
                    m_sAktDownloadDateiName = m_strukDownloadFile.sFileName + m_strukDownloadFile.sDateiendung;
                    m_pFTP->list();
                    m_pFTP->get(sDownlodFileName, actionFile);
                    m_strukDownloadFile.xAktive = false;
                    downloadMehrereDateien();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void FTPManager::connectToFtp(QString sServerIp)
    {
        m_pFTP->connectToHost(sServerIp, 21);

        qDebug() << "Connecting to FTP server " << sServerIp;
    }
```

Application output says: "Connecting to FTP server  "172.18.16.121""

EDIT2:

i made a new small project with the same Problem:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/13704266/qftptest.rar

Comment: you should see some error messages in application output that can help you

Comment: If it works in debug and does not work in release you can have some file missing from your release directory (like a config file with setting for your connection) . But as Evgenyi says it is much easier for us if you check the errors you see in console.

Comment: i dont have any errors, i call this " m_pFTP->connectToHost(sServerIp, 21);"
but no signal appears, like "commandFinished" or "commandStarted" or "stateChanged"
But if i use the debug mode its all fine, i can download files, and get signals...

Comment: Sorry, I've tried to run your example but it didn't compile. Which version of Qt are you using? Your .pro.user file says it is 5.6 but in 5.6 QFtp is no longer available, did you hack it in any way or I'm missing something?